# Restore old installation after new install

Tags: installation, restore

After my laptop came back from the customer service (new keyboard) I found it was impossible to boot it.
I used a LiveCD to copy all the data in an external memory, then I started a fresh new installation (I was unable to restore grub).
I think I made a mistake at this point and repartitioned the disk.
Then I copied the backup in the new installation. It turned out this doesn't work because of mismatches between the old and new partition table.
**Is there a way to restore the system without manually reinstalling all the software?**

Comment: Can you be more specific on your problem and what sort of back up you are using? If you are restoring a partition, recreate the partition scheme If you are simply restoring data, do a fresh install and restore your data.

Comment: All my data are in an external hard disk, copied using 
    cp -prf / <destinatino_path>

I have a fresh install, but if I copy back the backup data, I have problems because of the different partitioning.
So, which data shall I NOT copy back?

Answer (score 1):

It seemed to me that the relevant informations for partitioning and booting are contained in `/boot` and `/etc/fstab`. So I copied the complete backed-up system, with the exception of these 2 elements.

It seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would claim for compensation (responsibility?) at the customer service point where you've *changed you laptop's keyboard*, because to change keyboard does not (should not) modify the contest on your HDD.

Anyway, here you can find the answer to your question:
[Backup, clean install and restore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214665/backup-clean-install-and-restore?rq=1).